# Can you pass an instance of a class from inside a class in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm implementing a fragment, and on the edit of a text (using TextWatcher), I'm passing data to the parent activity using an interface.

I'm wondering though if it's possible to pass the instance of the class itself as the data being passed to the activity? So that I don't have to transfer every single String field one parameter at a time.

So could I do;

Activity:

```
Fragment frag = new FragmentClass();
// ... start the fragment
```

The in FragmentClass.java:

```
editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    ...
    public void afterTextChanged(...) {
    listener.onChangedListener(PASS IN THE INSTANCE OF THE CLASS ITSELF???);
    }
});
```

This is to avoid needing to do:

```
listener.onChangedListener(String field1, String field2, String field3, etc..);
```

Comment: But your addTextChangedListener will give only one string at a time then why do you need to pass any class instance. In case you are using the same callback for others as well maintain an enum as which edit text and pass the data.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that second part? I am using the same callback for every edittext (and its corresponding string field). Do you mean I just add a second parameter with "id" or something like that based on what field is being changed and still just pass one string at a time? @AnkitAman

Comment: yes define something like onChangedListener(enum EditTextType, String field), So your EditTextType will have some Name,Email.... Or you can go with id or tag as well passing anything which is unique for others.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you corrent so you should do somethink like this

```
    listener.onChangedListener(FragmentClass.this);
```

And on other side your listener should receive the instance of this class

```
    interface MyListener {
        void onChangedListener(FragmentClass fragmentClass);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access a public property on your parent activity from your fragment. Not sure if this is what you want to accomplish. You can try this.

In Activity

```
public String myText;
```

In Fragment

```
YourActivity parentActivity;
parentActivity = (YourActivity)getActivity(); 

//access the string property of your activity or do something else. Ex. parentActivity.myText = "Sample text"
```

This is just draft of a code on what I can remember as I am not on an IDE right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create DTO(data transfer object, just simple class) class.

```
class MyClass {
   String field1;
   String field2;
   String field3;
   MyClass(
       String field1,
       String field2,
       String field3
   ) {
     this.field1 = field1;
     this.field2 = field2;
     this.field3 = field3;
   }
}
```

And use it like:

```
MyClass dto = MyClass(field1, field2, field3);
listener.onChangedListener(dto);
```